# c# transform ref_cursor into a list ar a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I was wondering how to transform ref_cursor with a table of results generated by a stored procedure into a list or dictionary,I mean this:

stored proc procedure(userID in integer,result out sys_refcursor);
returns a table 6*5 or smtng similar

now we call this procedure from c# and we have a ref_cursor in C# =>

At this point how to transform ref_cursor into a dictionary/list???

hope you could show some examples or usefull links :)

Comment: @mike01010 yes we use like two class combo to transform refcursor into a list lol, but where could I find some documentation about that transformation, this is like some sort of secret only shared between the chosen ones... this is simple It should be like max 5 lines of code to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm clear what you are asking...
I don't think you can magically transform a cursor into  dictionary without first reading the data into some datatable, dataset or some other local storage.